# MySQL Error on Startup: ambiguous option '--log=/var/log/mysqld.log'

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, logging

I would like to try MySQL 5.6 on my machine, but I cannot start it. I always get an error :

> [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86/bin/mysqld: ambiguous option '--log=/var/log/mysqld.log' (log-bin, log_slave_updates)

### my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
pid-file=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86/mysql.pid
log-error=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86/data/mysql-error.log
log-slow-queries=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86/data/mysql-slowquery.log
log-bin=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86/data/mysql-bin.log
general_log_file=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86/data/mysql-general_log_file.log
log=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86/data/mysql.log
```

I tried to set the `log` and `log-bin` parameters in `my.cnf` and also as start parameters for mysqld, but with no luck. Any idea what I can do?

### My environment

```
OS X 10.6.8
mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86 (not _x64 version)
```

Note: I'm also running MySQL 5.5 on this machine (different port and socket). I also try to stop this instance but I get the some error.

**Update:**
Thank you for help but I'm still gettings the some error. I have now changed `my.cnf` to:

```
[mysqld]
user        = myusername
port        = 3307
socket      = /tmp/mysql_56.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 256M
group_concat_max_len = 50240
max_allowed_packet = 16777216
table_open_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size= 16M
thread_concurrency = 8
datadir=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86/data
pid-file=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86/mysql.pid
log-error=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86/data/mysql-error.log
log-slow-queries=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86/data/mysql-slowquery.log
log-bin=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86/data/mysql-bin.log
general-log=1
general_log_file=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86/data/mysql-general_log_file.log
```

And I start MySQL with a script:

```
cd /usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86
./bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86
cd $HOME
```

But I'm still getting the same error:

> 120611 16:02:02 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from
>   /usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86/data
>
> 120611 16:02:02 [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86/bin/mysqld: ambiguous option '--log=/var/log/mysqld.log' (log-bin, log_slave_updates)
>
> 120611 16:02:02 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 120611 16:02:02 [Note] Binlog end
>
> 120611 16:02:02 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql-5.6.5-m8-osx10.6-x86/mysql.pid ended

This is very strange because I did not set `--log=/var/log/mysqld.log` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your start.sh is using the correct my.cnf with `--defaults-file=/path/to/my.cnf`

You may also have another my.cnf automatically being included (usually `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) that could be adding/overriding options in your base config file.

Comment: Hi! Yes, this was my problem - another my.cnf in /etc/my.cnf. I remove this file and now it starts. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

The "ambiguous option" error message should have pointed you in the right direction...
The [`--log`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log) option has been long deprecated, use the [`--general-log`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_general-log) option instead

Please post your other errors messages so that we can help you with them.